# Windows C Socket Check For Disconnect

Tags: c, windows, sockets, connectivity

I am trying to write an application that communicates with a server via Sockets on windows. I need a reliable way of telling if the connection is interrupted, for example by internet connectivity issues etc. I do not mean the return of connect(), but while the socket has already been esablished.So far the only one that was supposed to work was to send a message to the server with

```
int issocketclosed = send(socketFd," \b",3,0);
```

My integer however does not change when the connection gets killed. On the server side i am using "netcat -k -lv PORT" to listen for the connection and to simulate interruption i am CTRL-C -ing netcat .

My Socket code looks something like this:

```
WSADATA wsa;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);
HANDLE s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
struct sockaddr_in connect_info;
connect_info.sin_family = AF_INET;
connect_info.sin_port = htons( port );
connect_info.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddr);
connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&connect_info,sizeof(connect_info));
while(1){

  Sleep(5000); //Do Stuff with socket

  int issocketclosed = send(socketFd," \b",3,0); //Check for connectin error
  if(issocketclosed == -1){
    connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)&connect_info,sizeof(connect_info)); // Reconnect
  }
}
```

I know this is not the first time this question has been asked but i have tried the other ones such as getsocketopt() without success. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use recv() to detect broken socket instead of send()

Comment: the return value of "recv()"?

Answer (score 1):

1. `send()` will *eventually* return -1 when sending over a connection that has been terminated by the peer, but due to socket buffering it won't happen on the first `send()` after the disconnect.
2. `recv()` will return zero on a cleanly closed connection, or -1 on an aborted one.
3. You can't reconnect a socket. You have to close it, create a new one, and connect that.
4. You aren't checking for errors on `socket()` or `connect()`. You must check the result of *every* system call for -1, and print or log `errno` or `perror()` or `strerror()` when you get it, so you know what the actual error was.